# Container exits instead of running in the background

Tags: meteor, docker, dockerfile

The Dockerfile here is used to crate the image `image/name`, then run to create the container, but `docker ps` report service exited. It was expected to remain running in order to serve the web site but not doing this. How can it be fixed?

```
//Dockerfile
FROM lambdalinux/baseimage-amzn:2016.09-000
RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
RUN yum install -y tar nodejs
COPY ./bundle /opt/bundle/
WORKDIR /opt/bundle/programs/server/
RUN npm install
CMD node ./main.js
```

And on the command line `docker run -tid -p 80:80 image/name`

Comment: If you run `node ./main.js` yourself, does it stay in the foreground or does it either exit or run in the background?

Comment: seems to me your service inside the container exits and therefore the container as well. Have you looked into the logs of the container? ```docker logs <your-container-name>```

Comment: @larsks on the server prompt, `node ./main.js` reports command not found,  `docker logs` reports no errors. Which tells me node is not installed... hummm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks it is trivial error.

It is expected that `main.js` is available under `/` directory as per last line of `Dockerfile` i.e.,
`CMD node ./main.js`

However, I believe that, `main.js` is available under `/opt/bundle/programs/server/` directory.

Now you have the options to run the `main` application.

## 1 without modifying image:

Just change the `docker run` and tell which application to be invoked

```
docker run -tid -p 80:80 image/name node /opt/bundle/programs/server/main.js
```

## 2 without modifying image: mount a local directory from host to container:

Same as in 1st case. Let us assume that application is not available in side image and available in host/local machine. So, mount local directory to container and run that application. In this case, there is an application `app2.js` in the current directory.

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/share -itd image/name node /share/app2.js
```

## 3 Modify image, refer absolute path in `CMD`:

Remove the existing image. Modify `Dockerfile` and change the below statement from

```
CMD node ./main.js
```

To

```
CMD node /opt/bundle/programs/server/main.js
```

Now rebuild the image.  In this case, you do not have to mention, which application to be run, in the command while running container. Unlike above, if you see option #1, #2, it is also specified which application to be invoked when container is run. Instead can simply run the image as image knows which application be run by default.

```
docker run -tid -p 80:80 image/name
```

`Exited` status is shown when docker container finishes / completes the process running inside.

`main.js` could not be located in the right location, process finished immediately and container exited in your case.

Hope this is helpful.